# Website with HTTP Redirects to ww4

Tags: http, https

**Hi,**
My website **bluestock.co** work fine with *https* but when I try to access with *http* It redirects to ww4 OR ww12

I'm using vestap cp and have three domains, other two are working fine but this one is making trouble.

Any help will be appreciated a lot

Comment: what http server are you using?  if apache check your .htaccess file.

Comment: @ELaRoche I got the solution, it was an old entry in DNS btw thanks